# React Native Router Flux Tabbar not showing

Tags: react-native, tabbar, react-native-router-flux

I am trying to add a Tabbar to my project but it's not working. I only want the Tabbar to show in my `homeScreen.js` scene, and there I want a tabbar which will open up my `discoverScreen.js`, how would I go about changing my code to make this work?

```
    render(){

return (
  <Router>
    <Scene key="root">

    <Scene
      key="tabbar"
      tabs
      tabBarStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }}
      >
        <Scene key="Discover" title="Discover" icon={TabIcon}>
          <Scene key="discoverScreen"
            component={DiscoverScreen}
            title="DiscoverScreen"
            initial
          />
        </Scene>
      </Scene>

    <Scene key="login"
      component={LoginView}
      title="Login"
      direction="vertical"
      hideNavBar
      />
    <Scene key="register"
      component={Register}
      title="Register"
      direction="vertical"
      hideNavBar
      />

    <Scene key="firstScreen"
    component={FirstScreen}
    title="FirstScreen"
    direction="vertical"
    hideNavBar
    initial
    />
    <Scene key="discoverScreen"
      component={DiscoverScreen}
      title="DiscoverScreen"
      direction="vertical"
      type="reset"
      />
    <Scene key="loginScreen"
      component={LoginScreen}
      title="LoginScreen"
      direction="vertical"
      hideNavBar
      />
      <Scene key="homeScreen"
        component={HomeScreen}
        title="HomeScreen"
        />


    </Scene>
  </Router>
);
```

}
}

Thankful for any help!